Lucia auth sveltekit problem with locals.user
I'm trying out Lucia with MongoDB, but there's an issue. Whenever I sign in a user, I can see that the user is successfully inserted into the database. However, when I navigate to another route, I'm redirected back to the sign-in page, even though I just signed in. What could be causing this issue?
i tried debuggin some data, from hooks.server.ts but it still shows me null

Show your code.

i just followed the default boilerplate in lucia documentation

Lucia auth documentation for mongodb sveltekit 

We probably need to see some code to be able to spot potential errors.

All relevant code has to be in the question, linking to some page that may or may not exist later and can change content at any time is not enough.
